# Password Function Error

Tags: c, function, while-loop

```
void main()
{
    Password();
}


void Password()
{
    //declare local variables//
    char cPassCode[] = "String";
    int iFlag, iComparison = 0;

    //Run the code to check the password//
    while (iFlag = 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter the password: ");
        scanf("%s", cPassCode);
        iComparison = strcmp(cPassCode,"A23bc5");
        if (iComparison == 0)
        {
            Header();
            ArrayPrinter(Array);
            iFlag = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong password");
            iFlag = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I've got this code for my program. The whole program runs fine but it goes through the loops again. I think it has to do with my while loop.  If I try changing the condition, the program doesn't run at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is here: `while (iFlag = 1)` you're not comparing `iFlag` to 1, you're setting it to 1.  One correct way to do this is `while (iFlag == 1)` but a safer way to phrase that is: `while (1 == iFlag)` so that the compiler will pick up when you make the ==/= error next time.  But the best way of all, since iFlag is being used as a boolean, is to simply do `while (iFlag)`

Next, you need to initialize `iFlag` before you use it:

```
int iFlag = 1, iComparison = 0;
```

And finally, this is not a good way to initialize `cPassCode`:

```
char cPassCode[] = "String";
```

As you don't know how many characters the user will type in -- use a larger value, something like:

```
#define MAXIMUM_INPUT_SIZE 1024
// ...
char cPassCode[MAXIMUM_INPUT_SIZE];
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop sets `iFlag = 1`, so it is always true.  You want the comparison operator instead `iFlag == 1`.  Also, you should initialize `iFlag` to `1` instead of zero so that your new loop works.   Lastly, you should malloc `cPassCode`, though that isn't making your program crash (probably).